# Client Peoplepicker not saving data to a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, people-picker, clientpeoplepicker

we are using Client peoplepicker in our SP custom form. Below is the code for that.

```
    function getUserInfo(peoplePickerElementId) {
    try{            
        var toSpanKey = peoplePickerElementId+ "_TopSpan";
        var peoplePicker = null;
        var ClientPickerDict = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict;
        for (var propertyName in ClientPickerDict) {
             if (propertyName == toSpanKey) {
                  peoplePicker = ClientPickerDict[propertyName];
                  break;
             }
        }
        if (peoplePicker != null) {  
            // Get information about all users.
            var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
            var userInfo = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                for (var userProperty in user) { 
                    userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
                }
            }
            // Get user keys.
            var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
            if(users[0].Key != null && users[0].Key != '') {
               // $('#userKeys').html(keys);
               var u=users[0].Key;
               // Get the first user's ID by using the login name.

                var userId = getUserId(users[0].Key);
                alert(userId);
            }
        }
      }
      catch(err){}
}
function getUserId(loginName){
    var userId=-1;
    /// get the site url
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
    var payload = { 'logonName': loginName}; 
    /// make an ajax call to get the site user
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/ensureuser",
        method: "POST",
        async:false,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        headers: {
             "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
             "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            userId=data.d.Id;
        },
        error: function (data) {            
        }
    });
    return userId;
}
```

code was working fine when we were using       `var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;`

in our code. But now we have changed it to       `var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;`
as users dont have acccess to root site. so now  `userId=data.d.Id;` no user ID is returning here. Please asssit.

Comment: Off topic suggestion - Do not use async: false. It is a bad practice. Try to use js promises instead.

Comment: I tried your code on SP 2013 -  It works with _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl and  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl. No issues. I suggest to rework your code by this way(see answer) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259576/sharepoint-2013-ensureuser-via-rest-api

Comment: @Raf it started working with async:false, somehow. i dont have in depth knowledge of javascript, any clue why it was not working without that and why we should not use it in our code?

Comment: @adarsg-awasthi because this option is deprecated. It is recommend to rewrite your ajax call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448011/jquery-ajax-methods-async-option-deprecated-what-now